# Storage components in openstack

Tags: cloud, storage, openstack

I am new to openstack and i have a few questions about storage in openstack : `Glance` store images and their metadata, `Swift` store actual virtual disk files, aiming at data durability. But what is the `nova-volume`(or the Block Storage) for? What is **volume** exactly?

And what is the difference between these components and real file system? What is **virtual disk** ,do they really be stored in the real file disk?

Comment: This comment would be more suited to serverfault.com, since it doesn't directly relate to programming.

Answer (score 3):

You're a bit confused about the storage components.

Glance is an image *registry*. Its main job is to store metadata about images for instances (kernels, root disk images, etc). It can also store those images, but the storage is configurable -- it can be local disk or swift.

Swift is an *object store*. It stores objects in buckets. You could think of buckets as directories and objects as files if that would help.

nova-volume (now replaced by Cinder) is a *block store*. It stores filesystems, and can be used for disk images on instances.

Virtual disks are the disks used by the virtual machines openstack manages (called instances in openstack speak). They are stored as either files on the compute node filesystem, or as block storage, depending on configuration.